# I need to prove that this Harry Potter problem is NP-Hard. To what problem can it be compared for reduction?

Tags: np-complete, decision-problems

Harry Potter is looking for a bowtruckle that is hiding in a graph and has made
itself invisible. Harry tries to find the bowtruckle by casting the spell rivilio trullio while aiming his
wand at a vertex of the graph. The first time he hits the bowtruckle it will stay invisible but move
to a neighbouring vertex of the graph. However, Harry will not be able to notice this because the
bowtruckle moves silently. The second time that Harry hits the bowtruckle it will become visible.
Harry’s wand has just enough energy left to cast the spell rivilio trullio k times. Therefore, Harry
wants to know whether he can choose at most k vertices of the graph such that he is sure that he will
find the bowtruckle when he casts rivilio trullio on each of these vertices. Show that this problem is
NP-complete.

I proved that the problem is NP, by showing it can be checked in polynomial time. Now I need to show its NP-Hard. To what problem can it be compared for reduction?

Comment: What is a "bowtruckle" ?

Comment: A character from the movie

Comment: No information about the graph structure ?

Comment: Are you aware of methods like here for the NP-completeness of the minesweeper game : https://www.weizmann.ac.il/sci-tea/benari/sites/sci-tea.benari/files/uploads/softwareAndLearningMaterials/minesweeper-en.pdf ?

Comment: There is an obvious solution (shamelessly stolen from a certain famous Harry Potter fanfiction): thanks to Time-Turners and canonical PoA time-travel mechanics, complexity is constant-time as soon as there is an algorithm that iterates through possibilities and stops at satisfactory ones only. Such an algorithm clearly exists in this case. 

 (If you want a more serious solution, please make the problem statement as clear as possible, for instance by removing all irrelevant elements.)